# What is the difference between circularly symmetric complex gaussian channel and rayleigh fading?

Tags: digital-communications

What is different between circularly symmetric complex gaussian  channel and rayleigh fading? or are they the same?

I Saw the method of creating circularly symmetric complex gaussian in this website, https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_generate_circularly_symmetric_complex_gaussian_CSCG_noise ,and it said

> sqrt(var/2) * (randn(1,N)+1i*randn(1,N))

.

On the other hand ,i saw the method of creating rayleigh fading in this matlab website : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30477-ber-curve-for-bpsk-in-rayleigh-channel , it said  h =

> 1/sqrt(2) * [randn(1,length(tx)) + j*randn(1,length(tx))];

So does it mean that when the variance is 1, circularly symmetric complex gaussian  channel is the same as  rayleigh fading?

Comment: if multiply a complex gaussian by its conjugate, what is the resulting distribution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: I don't read or comprehend MATLAB and so cannot talk about code snippets but you might want to read [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43482/235) for a high-level theoretically-oriented discussion of the relationship between complex Gaussian noise and Rayleigh fading.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz What do you want to say?

Comment: @Sylvindrunner that a little work on your part could answer your own question.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz  i mean  what are you trying to say or explain ?

Comment: @BlackMath the website doesn't explain their difference

Comment: what is the relationship between a Gaussian and Rayleigh?  Did Socrates have this problem?

Comment: I just know the fading meaning in rayleigh "fading" means the signal amplitude will vary randomly,not something decreasing

Comment: @@What? Socrates?that Greek philosopher?

Comment: What is Socratic method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100114/discussion-between-sylvindrunner-and-stanley-pawlukiewicz).

Comment: no thanks, i have other things to do

Comment: fine,i think you just make trouble here

Comment: @Sylvindrunner Read the article again. It's there in the first few lines.