# How is the distribution of the received signal affected if the transmitted signal is changed from complex Gaussian to PSK

Tags: digital-communications, gaussian, fading-channel, probability-distribution-function

Suppose the received signal is $y(n) = h_0s(n)+w(n)$----(1)

Where $h_0, s(n), w(n)$ all are distributed as zero mean complex Gaussian. Thus I know that $y(n)$ will also have the same distribution.

If $s(n)$ is a PSK signal instead of zero mean complex Gaussian then what will be the distribution of $y(n)$?

According to my understanding, if $s(n)$ is PSK signal then it is basically an unknown deterministic signal and hence will be constant. $h_0$ is also constant for the duration of the transmission. Therefore distribution of $y(n)$ depends only on $w(n)$ and so $y(n)$ will be distributed as zero mean complex Gaussian.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: *According to my understanding*, no that's up to you to *define*; however, usually, we model data signals as random signals with a discrete distribution (if not pulse-shaped).

Comment: Ok. ... if data signals are modeled as random signals then $s(n)$ being PSK will also be random...Then what distribution we should take for $s(n)$....

Comment: I've already written an answer that explains that. Also, this really becomes *very* basic stochastics now.

Comment: "Where h0,s(n),w(n) all are distributed as zero mean complex Gaussian. Thus I know that y(n) will also have the same distribution." This is not correct. Please clarify if $h_0$ is considered constant because the product of two normal random variables is not normal distributed.

Answer (score 0):

> ... $s(n)$ ... will be constant...
>
> Is my understanding correct?

No.

If that was the case, your data signal would have zero variance. That's not the case.

You need to model your data symbols as random. Typically that means you assume that $s(n) \in \{1, j, -1, -j\}, P(s(n)=1)=P(s(n)=j)=P(s(n)=-1)=P(s(n)=-)=\frac14$, i.e. discrete uniformly distributed.

Comment: Ok.. it means $s(n)$ will have uniform distribution...

Comment: **discrete** uniform, not *continuous* uniform. Again, **this is up to your model to define**, that's why I said "typically". I don't know how *you* model your data, your channel and your noise.

Comment: Yes ...Discrete Uniform...

Comment: In case of $s(n)$ as QPSK there are 4 discrete uniformly distributed random variables...then distribution of $y(n)$ will be distribution of 4 discrete uniform distribution plus Gaussian distribution.... Am I correct?

Comment: no, there aren't 4 random variables.

Comment: OK...Will Check it

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding that "Thus I know that $y[n]$ will have the same distribution" (that is, be zero-mean complex Gaussian because $h_0, s[n], w[n]$ all are zero-mean complex Gaussian) is incorrect.  It *is* true that the sum of independent zero-mean complex Gaussian random variables is a zero-mean complex Gaussian random variable (with a different variance), but how can you be sure that the *product* $h_0s[n]$ of two complex Gaussian random variables is itself a complex Gaussian random variable?  A more realistic model is where $s[n]$ is a discrete-valued complex number such as $s[n] \in \{1,j,-1,-j\}$ as in MarcusMuller's answer or $\big\{\sqrt{\mathscr E_s},j\sqrt{\mathscr E_s},-\sqrt{\mathscr E_s},-\sqrt{\mathscr E_s}\big\}$ if you want to stick the symbol energy $\mathscr E_s$ in there, and **conditioned on the value of $s[n]$,** $y[n]$ is a complex Gaussian random variable with mean the given value of $s[n]$. A given value for $s[n]$ means that (conditionally) $h_0s[n]$ is just another complex Gaussian random variable independent of the noise $w[n]$ and so is $y[n] = h_0s[n]+w[n]$ a (conditionally) complex Gaussian random variable with mean $s[n]$.

See also [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43482/235) to understand some of the modeling issues involved.